# Why my winner check function does not work correctly?

Tags: python, algorithm, function, logic, game-development

I am working on connect4 game, now I am on winner checking part, but the winnercheck function does not work correctly. How to fix that?
In pycharm editor it says that the variable winner is not used even it is used. And after four same digits verticaly it is not printing who is the winner. I am not sure how to fix it.
Thank you!

```
from termcolor import colored

field = [[" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "], [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "], [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "], [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "], [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "], [" ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " "]]


def drawField(field):
    for row in range(11):
        if row % 2 == 0:
            rowIndex = int(row / 2)
            for column in range(13):
                if column % 2 == 0:
                    columnIndex = int(column / 2)
                    if column == 12:
                        print(field[rowIndex][columnIndex])
                    else:
                        print(field[rowIndex][columnIndex], end="")
                else:
                    print("|", end="")
        else:
            print("-------------")


def reset():
    for i in range(6):
        for b in range(7):
            field[i][b] = " "


drawField(field)
Player = 1


def winnerCheck(characters):

    maxSQ = 0
    char = False
    sq = 0
    for i in characters:
        if i != char:
            char = i
            sq = 1
        else:
            sq += 1
        if sq > maxSQ:
            maxChar = char
            maxSQ = sq
            if maxChar == "X" or maxChar == "O":
                if maxSQ == 4:
                    winner = 0
                    if maxChar == "X":
                        winner = "1"
                    else:
                        winner = "2"
                    print("--------------------------------------")
                    print("|  The winner is player", winner, end="")
                    print("      |")
                    print("--------------------------------------")


while True:
    rowIndex = False
    currentChoice = False
    print("Player turn:", Player)
    column = int(input("Please enter a column: ")) - 1
    if column <= 6:
        print(True)
    else:
        print("You can choose numbers only between 1 and 7 included!")
        continue
    if Player == 1:
        for i in range(5, -1, -1):
            if field[0][column] != " ":
                print("This column is already filled up! You can't put here anymore!")
                full = 0
                for b in range(7):
                    if field[0][b] != " ":
                        full += 1
                if full == 7:
                    print("There is no winner!")
                    reset()
                break
            else:
                if field[i][column] != " ":
                    continue
                else:
                    field[i][column] = colored("X", "red")
                    drawField(field)
                    Player = 2
                    currentChoice = field[i][column]
                    rowIndex = i
                    break
    else:
        for i in range(5, -1, -1):
            if field[0][column] != " ":
                print("This column is already filled up! You can't put here anymore!")
                full = 0
                for b in range(7):
                    if field[0][b] != " ":
                        full += 1
                if full == 7:
                    print("There is no winner!")
                    reset()
                break
            else:
                if field[i][column] != " ":
                    continue
                else:
                    field[i][column] = colored("O", "green")
                    drawField(field)
                    currentChoice = field[i][column]
                    Player = 1
                    rowIndex = i
                    break
    characters = []


    for i in range(6):
        print(i)
        characters.append(field[i][column])
    print(characters)
    winnerCheck(characters)
```

Comment: You get a lint error for `winner` not used because you assign a value to `winner` and then immediately assign another value, the statement `winner = 0` has no effect except to perform an unnecessary task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue is in these lines of code:

```
if maxChar == "X" or maxChar == "O":
```

and a bit further down:

```
if maxChar == "X":
```

These conditions will never be true because your characters are never "X" or "O", but are ANSI escape codes generated by calls to `colored`, like `'\x1b[31mX\x1b[0m'`

This is a mixup between "model" and "view" aspects of your code.

The best fix is to not store the result of `colored()` in your `field` list. Instead just store plain "X" and "O" values. Then in your `drawField` function, do the necessary to bring color to your output.

So change:

```
field[i][column] = colored("X", "red")
```

To

```
field[i][column] = "X"
```

and make the same change for where you have `colored("O", "green")`.

Then in `drawField` change:

```
    if column == 12:
        print(field[rowIndex][columnIndex])
    else:
        print(field[rowIndex][columnIndex], end="")
```

to:

```
    ch = field[rowIndex][columnIndex]
    output = colored(ch, "red" if ch == "X" else "green")
    if column == 12:
        print(output)
    else:
        print(output, end="")
```

#### Some other remarks:

Your code will only detect a vertical four in a row. Currently you only pass the information about one column to `winnerCheck`. You'll want to extend this function to detect also horizontal and diagonal wins...

There is unnecessary code repetition. Like the two blocks that are in the `if Player == 1 .... else` construct. You should try to make that just one block, as the only difference is what you assign to `field[i][column]`.

As mentioned in comments you have a `winner=0` that has no effect, since you immediately assign a different value to it. You can initialise `winner` in one go:

```
winner = "1" if maxChar == "X" else "2"
```

The check for a draw should not require that a user makes an invalid move. You should detect the draw when the last valid move has been made.